# How do you make an in app button keyboard in an activity?

Tags: android, kotlin, ascii, keycode

How can you make an in-app buttons that works like the keyboard?

I am trying to load a website(which is coded using javascript) into my app using the webView function. But unfortunately, the interactive design of the website requires the user to type in letters from the computer keyboard. I could easily pull up the keyboard on the android device to type, but it is a bit too inconvenient as I only need to use 5 buttons.

I used Kotlin to try inserting a letter to the webView browser, but I can't find a solution just yet. Is there a way to make a shortcut or a set of a library that allows me to do so? Thank you for your replies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to dispatch `KeyEvents` to the `WebView`. For example, the following code simulates a left key press.

```
webView.dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_LEFT))
```

Here's an [article](http://jules.dourlens.com/send-keybords-event-android-webview/) for further reference. The list of possible `KeyEvent` codes is available in the [official docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#constants_1).

Comment: PERFECT, exactly what I wanted. Works on the first try. Thank you very much